# How to download XML files from Firebase Storage?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, firebase-storage

I am working on personal project for AIR Android.I am using REST API with Action Script 3.0. I have successfully implemented the authentication, uploading and deleting files but I am unable to download files. I only have xml files and each user has his/her files.  Here is what I tried.

First I get a new token:

```
private function refreshToken(idToken:String):void
    {
        var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var myObject:Object = new Object();
        myObject.grant_type = "authorization_code";
        myObject.code = idToken;

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key="+FIREBASE_API_KEY);
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        request.data = JSON.stringify(myObject);
        request.requestHeaders.push(header);

        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, refreshTokenLoaded);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
        loader.load(request);   
    }
```

Once the new token has been loaded:

```
private function refreshTokenLoaded(event:flash.events.Event):void
    {
        trace("idToken refreshed!");
        var rawData:Object = JSON.parse(event.currentTarget.data);
        var newIdToken:String = rawData.access_token;
        settings.xmlDB.oauthAccessToken.@value = newIdToken;
        settings.updateXML();

        downloadMetadata();

        trace(event.currentTarget.data);
    }
```

Before downloading the file, I get the metadata for that file:

```
private function downloadMetadata(authToken:String):void
    {
        var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+authToken);         

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/spesa-febea.appspot.com/o/data%2F"+settings.xmlDB.localId.@value+"%2FDatabase");
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        request.requestHeaders.push(header);

        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, metadataLoaded);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
        loader.load(request);

    }
```

"Database" is the name of the one of the files. Once the metadata has been loaded:

```
private function metadataLoaded(event:Event):void
    {
        trace(event.currentTarget.data);
        var rawData:Object = JSON.parse(event.target.data);

        trace("DOWNLOAD TOKENS: ", rawData.downloadTokens);
       downloadPrivateFile(rawData.downloadTokens, "Database", settings.xmlDB.localId.@value);
    }
```

then I attempt to download the file:

```
private function downloadPrivateFile(downloadTokens:String, fileName:String, localId:String):void
    {
        trace("downloading");
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/spesa-febea.appspot.com/o/data%2F" + localId + "%2F" + fileName + "?alt=media&token="+downloadTokens);
        navigateToURL(request);

        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.load(request); // to get the contents of the xml
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileContentLoaded, false, 0, true);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler, false, 0, true);
    }
```

First I only tried 
    navigateToURL();
but that didn't seem to work so I tried using:

```
URLLoader();
```

to get the content of the xml files and then just paste that into the files stored on the device. But no matter what I do, I always get this error:

```
{
 "error": {
 "code": 403,
 "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
 }
}
```

The navigateToURL() shows the same error in the browser. While URLLoader show the same error in the output window. This also replaces the content of the xml file with the error - The file stored on the Firebase Storage. I tried rechecking the code. Metadata of the file is successful traced in the output window. I have checked my rules. There is no problem with the rules. I have been working on this for about a week now and still havn't been able to figure whats going on. Any help would be highly appreciated.

On further testing, I have found that the download token in the "download url" from the Firebase Stoage and from the the request.url(); is not the same.

Download url from Firebase:

This url when copied and pasted into the new tab, shows the correct content of the xml file
    https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/spesa-febea.appspot.com/o/data%2FUbgGtcJrt1MOV5ClC1LAEt2sLou1%2FDatabase?alt=media&token=1c94ab22-2260-4d3e-b5f9-28a746353b81

Download url from request.url():
While this url shows the aforementioned error and replace xml content with this it.
    https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/spesa-febea.appspot.com/o/data%2FUbgGtcJrt1MOV5ClC1LAEt2sLou1%2FDatabase?alt=media&token=6025eb7a-4453-4714-9150-4f3aec239615

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need open data in the *browser* use **navigateToURL(*rq*)** or if you want get data in your **app** then use [**URLLoader**].load()

   2. Please review **URLLoaderDataFormat** ( binary | text | variables ) the best with XML is text.
   3. Read about this: **URLRequestDefaults** (if you need use cache or need follow redirects)
   4. Remember **Error HTTP 403 Forbidden** is possible that you need redirect your request and not create a new (may be you are loosing your token grants in the change)

Comment: You send a request to fb server and this response ok, with the data that you need redirect without close the parent request to get an ok final answer. But you are sending this data in a new request, then server don't know you and return the error.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding the authorization header to your call and it has to be a POST... Add this:

```
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+authToken);
```

...

```
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.requestHeaders.push(header);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but no luck. If I use the oauthAcessToken as "authToken" , i get the file metadata instead the of it's content and it also replaces the content of the file with the Permission denied error. And if I use idToken as "authToken", it outputs the error instead of metadata.